# Aliasing with many_to_many relation in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two classes: `User` and `Folder` that use a `has_many :through` to create a many_to_many relationship. I need to have aliases for both classes such that `Subscriber` is an alias for `User` and `Subscription` is an alias for `Folder`. In the end, I would like to be able to say:

```
user.subscriptions
```

and

```
folder.subscribers
```

Is this doable?  Currently I have defined a join class `SubscriptionSubscriber` like

```
class SubscriptionSubscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscription , class_name: "Folder"
  belongs_to :subscriber , class_name: "User"
end
```

and added the following code to `User` and `Folder`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscription_subscribers
  has_many :subscriptions, :through => :subscription_subscribers, :class_name => "Folder", :foreign_key => "subscription_id", :source => :folder
end

class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscription_subscribers
  has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscription_subscribers, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "subscriber_id", :source => :user
end
```

This is not working. For example, if I run

`user.subscription`

I get the following error

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: 
Could not find the source association(s) :folder in model SubscriptionSubscriber. 
Try 'has_many :subscriptions, :through => :subscription_subscribers, :source => <name>'. 
Is it one of subscription or subscriber?
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `:source`, we're telling Rails to look for an association called :subscription on the SubscriptionSubscriber model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscription_subscribers, foreign_key: "subscriber_id"
  has_many :subscriptions, through: :subscription_subscribers, source: :subscription
end

class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscription_subscribers, foreign_key: 'subscription_id'
  has_many :subscribers, through: :subscription_subscribers, source: :subscriber
end
```

After making this change, try now with fetching `user.subscriptions`

Comment: Thanks very much Sasidaran.